# Ошибка при работе с файлами и папкой

Tags: python

пытаюсь записать файлы в папку, но вылазит ошибка. Как исправить ?

```
import string
import os

def create_files():
    path = os.mkdir('path')
    for symbol in string.ascii_uppercase:
        with open(path/symbol + '.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            f.write(symbol)
    print('Создание файлов успешно завершено!')

create_files()
```

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался в задаче, нужно было перейти в другую директорию!

```
import string
import os

def create_files():
    if not os.path.isdir("path"):
        os.mkdir("path")
    os.chdir("path")
    for symbol in string.ascii_uppercase:
        with open(symbol + '.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            f.write(symbol)
    print('Создание файлов успешно завершено!')

create_files()
```

Comment: Нужно было читать текст ошибки. path/symbol - это в данном случае, пардон, полная хрень. И в директорию переходить не надо было, достаточно правильно указать путь.

Comment: хмм, написал так: "path / symbol + '.txt' " не работает

Comment: А с чего бы оно должно работать?

Comment: Фух, получилось сделать )) with open( 'path\ ' + symbol + '.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:

Comment: Для создания пути лучше использовать os.path.join(), тогда не нужно забивать голову кавычками итп. https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join

Comment: спасибо, попробовал так как вы сказали, действительно лучше способ